# Необходимо сделать с использованием рекурсии

Tags: python

Разработайте программу с рекурсивной функцией вычисление n первых членов геометрической прогрессии, первый член которой равен a и знаменатель q. Сделал код, но сомневаюсь в его правильности. Заранее спасибо.

```
def geom_prog(a, q, n, res=[]):
    if n == 0:
        return res + [a]
    return geom_prog(a * q, q, n - 1, res + [a])


print(geom_prog(2, 4, 8))`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуть чуть отредачил, а так вполне нормальный код.

```
def geom_prog(b, q, n):
    if n <= 1:
        return [b]
    return [b] + geom_prog(b * q, q, n-1)


print(geom_prog(1, 2, 8))
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо Вам большое.